# Encrypt in React Native, decrypt in Java

Tags: java, reactjs, react-native, encryption, aes

I need an easy solution for encrypt a string in AES from my React Native app, send to the server and the decrypt from there with Java.
I found some solutions but I am not able to make it works...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Easy solution: Use HTTPS.

Comment: `I found some solutions but I am not able to make it works...` please provide more details (e. g. code in React and in Java), otherwise we're guessing. Regardless that - are you trying something where https in not enough?

Answer (score 1):

For the Javascript/React Native side I've used [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) before which should just be a couple lines of code to implement.

`npm install crypto-js`

Then in your code

```
import AES from 'crypto-js/aes'

const stringToEncrypt = 'my string';
const secretKey = 'secret key 123';
const encryptedString = AES.encrypt(stringToEncrypt, secretKey).toString();
```

Then you can send encryptedString to your server, prefereably via https using something like [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: Thx, almost all the examples I found with AES are using a secret key with salt and an Initialization vector. I try to replicate the same then in Java, but the encrypted strings I get are different. In your example, do you know how to read that in Java?

Comment: On reflection yes you will need a key to encrypt via AES. You could store this securely on the server and in your React Native code using environment variables to keep it secure. I have updated my answer accordingly.

My Java isn't great so I would suggest looking up decryption using Cypher (import javax.crypto.Cipher) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html

Comment: In my case secret key is placed in a keystore file, how can i read and access key from  it in order to use  in react native to encrypt my plain text